# What is mdev and how to /dev/* nodes get created in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, devices, rootfs

Our Linux kernel is 2.6.31 running on an embedded MIPS processor with busybox.

The initialisation script (rcS) starts mdev with:

```
echo "/sbin/stbhotplug" > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
mdev -s
```

Can anyone tell me what the Linux utility mdev does?

It looks like it does auto hot plugging as the stbhotplug is a script that handle ethernet interfaces.

Also, the rootfs we have been given only has a console device i.e. `/dev/console` is the only file in `/dev`.

However, when the system is running, the `/dev` directory is full of device files (e.g. `/dev/mtd`, etc.).

The reason I ask is that occasionally we get an error whereby it is reported that `/dev/ubi_ctrl` is not found or `/dev/ubi1` is not found.

How or when does Linux create these devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [a link to the mdev primer](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/docs/mdev.txt?h=1_18_stable).

Comment: Whoa! I had to back step there because I clicked your to-the-point-link so quickly. Here's a well-deserved ^ =)

Answer (score 6):

mdev is a light-weight alternative to udev for usage in embedded devices. Both handle the creation of device files in `/dev` and starting of actions when certain events happen.

Comment: So if `/dev` devices are not being created, could be a problem with `mdev` or a timing issue?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand both could be true. But I only wrote the answer because I had just read about mdev in a news article yesterday. Generally I have no experience with it and cannot give any further assistance. That's why I posted my answer as a kick-start for a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

`mdev` basically calls `mknod` for a set of pre-configured device files.

If you have a choice, use instead:

```
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
```

which automatically mounts the special devtmpfs filesystem under `/dev`, and allows modules to automatically create their own device files on `insmod`, as shown at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970595/how-to-create-a-device-node-from-the-init-module-code-of-a-linux-kernel-module/45531867#45531867

This is what Buildroot and most distros currently do by default.